# Xamarin Debug > iPhone - you must now execute: lldb -s /tmp/mtouch-lldb-prep-cmds

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I "think" I was doing some debugging thing a while ago where I set something in Visual Studio for MAC to help me find an issue, I cannot recall what it is.

Do we have a Xamarin Columbo in the house?

When I run my project on Xamarin Debug > iPhone

All I get is "waiting to connect to Debugger", then this in the output

```
You must now execute: lldb -s /tmp/mtouch-lldb-prep-cmds
```

Can anyone tell me what I have set?

> > I have looked in my iOS csproj file for some odd property to no avail

EDIT: Sorry, I ended up reinstalling Visual Studio and the issue went away, but can no longer debug it.

Comment: could you see the list of devices when you want to debug ?

Comment: it seems to be no connection to the device

Comment: Hi @LeoZhu-MSFT, I have an iPad / iPhone XR connected via USB, but it won't seem to start, I thought I managed to kick off the debugger before by manually starting the app, but now that's not working.

Comment: Running the command lldb -s /tmp/mtouch-lldb-prep-cmds also does not start anything up.

Comment: what 's your device and VS version ?

Comment: 8.3.4 (build 8) - IOS 13.1.3

Comment: HI @LeoZhu-MSFT, I has to give up with this and did a full reinstall of my MAC, this issue no longer exists on my new install :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably trying to debug your Xamarin.iOS app using Xcode by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/debugging-with-xcode).

What you see is what you get in the Application Output after following the instructions

Comment: hi @papafe, sorry, I reinstalled a while back, but I think you are right although cannot confirm, I have updated the question accordingly and will mark as answer.

Comment: This is correct, but the question that remains is: How do we get it back to working normally, that is VS being able to start the app automatically?

Answer (score 1):

To get it working again normally (VS starts your app automatically) you have to delete this file:

```
~/.mtouch-launch-with-lldb
```

It was likely created using this command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/debugging-with-xcode#alternative---using-lldb